# Select by Attributes isn`t selecting anything

Tags: python, arcmap

I have a "Roads" feature class that has Paved (0) and Unpaved (1) roads. 
I want to select all Paved roads using Python, so I used this code in the Python window in arcmap:

```
qry = '"Subtype" = ' + "'0'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("Roads", "NEW_SELECTION", qry )
```

The command is working, but nothing gets selected on the map. 
I tried rearranging the hierarchy of the layers in the table of contents by placing the Roads layer as the topmost layer, but again, nothing gets selected.

Edit: I tried using the Select by Attributes command from the "Selection" tab, and manually entering the query, it successfully selects all paved roads.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your field a text or a numeric field? You don't need single quotes around the 0 for a numeric field.

Also, there is no need to use 2 separate strings to build this query.

Lastly, mixing single and double quotes to wrap your query isn't a good idea. Use triple double quotes to wrap everything instead:

```
qry = """"Subtype" = '0'"""
```

or

```
qry = """"Subtype" = 0"""
```

And if there are variable parts in your query (e.g. field name or field value), you can also use the Python [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function:

```
field_name = "Subtype"
field_value = 0

qry = """"{}" = '{}'""".format(field_name, field_value)
```

Comment: It`s a numeric field (Long Integer). I did try it without quotations, but it returned an error saying: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. I also tried your first method, it did succeed, but I`m still having the same issue, nothing gets selected, the data on the map just blinks as if it were altered, but nothing get highlighted.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the field properties and attribute values of your layer? If the field has subtypes, what are the subtype codes and subtype descriptions?

Comment: I added two screenshots, one depicting the Fields tab, and the other for the Subtypes tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer but as the attribute is an integer field try:

```
where_clause="Subtype = 0"
```